# Sinusoidal Inverter

Tags: power-supply, inverter, sine

I purchased a pure sine power inverter and noticed on the back there is a warning:

"Notice: The output of this device is not sinusoidal.  It has a total harmonic distortion of 3 percent and maximum single harmonic of 3 percent."

Does this mean the inverter is NOT a pure sine wave?  How can it be a pure sine and non-sinusoidal?

A related question: Is a typical 120v wall outlet not truly sinusoidal either due to noise / harmonics / etc?

Comment: "pure sine" is marketing ~~lies~~talk. "3% harmonic distortion" is (potentially) engineering truth, and close enough to being a nice clean sine wave that it (probably) doesn't matter.

Comment: Even expensive equipment like this R&S signal generator: https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/pl/product/smb100a-productstartpage_63493-9379.html does not output a "pure" sinewave. The sinewave it produces is **very clean** but still there will be some distortion and noise on it. Nevertheless, that sinewave is **good enough** for nearly all purposes. The same is true for your inverter, not a pure sine but **good enough** for any practical application. A wall outlet will indeed also contain noise and harmonics. This isn't an issue so no need to worry about "pure sinewaves".

Comment: 3% is pretty sine wavey. It's probably just there so you can't sue them.

Comment: 3% is better than 35% so it is marketing on the brochure, engineering on the back label.  This is rated with a resistive load. I expect it to increase with a pulsed load current like a laptop charger.

Answer (score 1):

> A related question: Is a typical 120v wall outlet not truly sinusoidal
>   either due to noise / harmonics / etc?

Typical wall outlets do have harmonics, and this is mostly dependent on the quality of the grid and other loads near whatever the device is plugged into. Harmonics are not usually an issue, devices with a rectifier and then a filter probably wouldn't even notice.

The problem is when devices that are plugged directly into AC mains such as motors, heaters and fans, the harmonics *do matter*. For motors this can be a change in torque. In one of the products I worked on, we had to use an isolation drive transformer to clean up the harmonics and dips that were causing a motor to change in RPM ever so slightly.